# wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName(className)) doesn't return any element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to find **IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>** using **WebDriverWait** to make sure that elements had been rendered on page.

This is my code

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
 return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName("TextInput")));
```

This code failing on timeout.
Meaning that could not find any elements on page with given class name.
I added this line of code **BEFORE** my original code just to make sure that elements are present

```
 var allInputs1 = container.FindElements(By.ClassName("textInput"));
```

And that line returns elements as expected.

So my conclustion is that
`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName("TextInput")))` 
doesn't work as expected since that couldn't find elements that are for sure present on page.

What is the best way to find array of elements using **WebDriverWait**?

Comment: The timeout means that some of the elements matching the class are still hidden. Try with with a more selective selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong. With `FindElements` you just make sure that elements are present.

The API documentation for `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` states:

> An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page
>   that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements
>   are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is
>   greater than 0.

And obviously *present* is not *visible*.

I think you should try `ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy`

Comment: Thank you for your answer , however I see the elements on page and I have already tried the PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy . FindElements would return 2 results and PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy would return 6 results - 4  of them are indeed not visible - hence the error in VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy . Where does my scope changes?

Comment: @Polina F. No, actually `findElements` wouldn't wait for element by provided locator so at time it just found only two while `PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` would wait until provided locator matches elements that's why you're seeing the difference, and VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy just do for presence and visibility both for all 6 elements that's why you're getting exception, so basically all methods are working perfect, you just change your thoughts only. Thanks..:)