# How to wait for a WebElement to be present within the DOM?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Currently I looking for a solution to wait for a specific WebElement to be present within the websites DOM.

Currently I have setup the below method which uses a By locator however I'm looking to use a WebElement instead, any ideas?

As per the JavaDocs:

*public static ExpectedCondition visibilityOf(WebElement element): An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.*

This existing method above, checks that the element is visible and also present in the DOM but not only present in the DOM.

Current method which uses By instead of WebElement:
I can see from reading the selenium documentation you can wait for the presence of an element to be visible within the DOM;

An Example:

```
public static void waitForElementToAppearInDOM(By by, int timer) {
    try {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        WebDriverWait exists = new WebDriverWait(driver, timer);
        exists.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty correct till *public static ExpectedCondition visibilityOf(WebElement element): An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. This existing method above, checks that the element is visible and also present in the DOM but not only present in the DOM*.

For simplicity I would rephrase this ExpectedCondition as *the expectation to check for the element known to be present within the DOM of a page, is visible*.

Of-coarse the two expectations `presenceOfElementLocated()` and `visibilityOf()` have a lot of differences between them.

---

Coming back to your main question, *to wait for a specific WebElement to be present* using  *WebElement* as an argument is **not possible** . The reason is simple as the *WebElement* is yet to be identified in the DOM, which will be identified only after the expectation of `presenceOfElementLocated` or `findElement()` succeeds.

This concept is abruptly supported by the list of [ExpectedCondition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)s in the *JavaDocs* related to *presence of element(s)* which are as follows:

- [`presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [`presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [`presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(By locator, By childLocator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [`presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(WebElement element, By childLocator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [`presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(By parent, By childLocator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

---

To conclude, you can't pass a *WebElement* as an argument as an expectation as `presenceOfElementLocated()` as the *WebElement* is yet to be identified. But once the element is identified through `findElement()` or `presenceOfElementLocated()` this *WebElement* can be passed an an argument.

To summarize:

- [`presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-): This expectation is for checking that an element is **present** in the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is **visible**.
- [`visibilityOf(WebElement element)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-): This expectation is for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only **displayed** but also has a **height** and **width** that is **greater than 0**.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

1. Presence means it exists in the DOM but is not necessarily visible, clickable, etc. If you want the element to be visible, then wait for visible.
2. You are using `*Elements*` which is plural which will wait for *ALL* elements found by the locator, not just the one you are specifically looking for. This can lead to confusing failures, etc. if you don't have a unique locator. I would avoid using plural if you only want singular.
3. You should read [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) carefully. There exists an `ExpectedConditions` method that does exactly what you are looking for.

> public static ExpectedCondition visibilityOf(WebElement element)

Your code should look more like

```
public static void waitForElementToAppearInDOM(WebElement element, int timer) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timer).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // don't leave an empty catch, do something with it or don't catch it.
    }
}
```

Comment: the java docs references: 'Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.'

Comment: @SamP I don't understand your point. If the element is "visible" but is 0 width x 0 height, it's not really visible, is it?

Comment: my point is im trying to validate solely if an element is present within the DOM, not whether its visible, for example if a specific div container is listed within the dom with a opacity of 0, display as none etc, it will still be listed within the DOM however from a users perspective they will not see the specific div tag.

Comment: @SamP Your confusion over presence vs visibility is confusing us as readers and is making it hard to understand and answer your question. Presence means the element is in the DOM but is not necessarily visible, clickable, etc. Visible means the element can be seen.. is visible and has a height and width. Now your question, as it is written right now is `How to wait for a WebElement to be **VISIBLE** within the DOM?` which clearly states you are looking for visible and not just presence. Please clarify and edit your question if you are changing your mind.

Comment: @SamP does visibilityOf apply an and logic to check for both presence and visibility? For example if one fails the other will also fail.

Comment: @SamP Can an element be visible without being present?

Comment: @SamP I'm confused as to why you even want this. If you already have located an element, why do you need to check for presence? If it wasn't there, you wouldn't have been able to locate it in the first place. If the page changes and you are trying to avoid `StaleElementException`s, then this is not the right way to do it. This sounds like [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than trying to get the specific solution you are looking for, instead describe the overall problem you are trying to solve. There's definitely a better way to solve this problem than this.

Comment: elements can still be loaded into the DOM even with a CSS height and width of 0, I'm already handling StaleElementExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This method "visibilityOfElementLocated" use By:

Example:
//To wait for element visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='text3']")));
```

Comment: Please don't publish multiple answers to the same question. Rather club up all your ideas and publish through a single canonical answer. Finally delete the redundant answer.

Answer (score 0):

How to check presence with `WebElement` as a parameter.

```
    public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
        if (element != null) {
            try {
//this line checks the visibility but it's not returned. 
//It's to perform any operation on the WebElement
                element.isDisplayed(); 
                return true;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return false;
            } 
        } else return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can have a try like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Comment: I'm afraid its till using By instead of WebElement.

Comment: i think there is no difference

Comment: @dudycoco You think there is no difference between a `By` and a `WebElement`?

Answer (score -3):

In your code, you should have the 'ID' or 'xpath' as locator. 
Look at the docs on [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
Line 5 would look like:

```
exists.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By, locator));
```

Also, look at this [presence of element not same as visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575177/wait-untilexpectedconditions-visibilityofallelementslocatedbyby-classnameclas).

Comment: thats correct, but im looking to replace By with WebElement.

Comment: ok, you can do this. Find the 'ID' of the web element. Replace 'locator' with 'ID'. Refer to the docs, also look at ' visibilityOf(WebElement element)'

Comment: the problem with visibilityOf, it performs two checks: 'Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.' instead of solely validating the element it in the DOM.